# How do I query the objects UtilElements and UtilIdElements to fetch correct results?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, ax

I am having issues with querying UtilElements and UtilIdElements in Dynamics AX 2009.

Screenshot **#1** shows the class SalesFormLetter being present in the layers `sys`, `syp`, `gls`, `glp` and `cup`. However, when I run the following the code the output displays that the object exists only in the `sys` layer. Output of this code is given in screenshot **#2**.

Am I doing something wrong in this code? I would like to know all the layers in which a given object is present.

Thanks in advance.

```
    #AOT

    UtilElements        utilElements;
    UtilIdElements      utilIdElements;
    ;

    info('Querying UtilElements...');

    while
        select      utilElements
        where       utilElements.name       == 'SalesFormLetter'
        &&          utilElements.recordType == UtilElementType::Class
    {
        info('Layer: ' + enum2str(utilElements.utilLevel) + 
                ', Object type: ' + enum2str(utilElements.recordType));
    }


    info('Querying UtilIdElements...');

    while
        select      utilIdElements
        where       utilIdElements.name         == 'SalesFormLetter'
        &&          utilIdElements.recordType   == UtilElementType::Class
    {
        info('Layer: ' + enum2str(utilIdElements.utilLevel) + 
                ', Object type: ' + enum2str(utilIdElements.recordType));
    }
```

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: SalesFormLetter]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are other element types involved like `UtilElementType::ClassStaticMethod` or `UtilElementType::ClassInstanceMethod`. Try running this:

```
static void UtilElementTest(Args _args)
{
    UtilElements        utilElements;
    ;
    setPrefix('Querying UtilElements...');
    while select utilElements
        where utilElements.parentId == classNum(SalesFormLetter)
        // && utilElements.recordType == UtilElementType::ClassInstanceMethod
           && utilElements.utilLevel != UtilEntryLevel::sys
    {
        info('Name: ' + utilElements.name +
             ', Layer: ' + enum2str(utilElements.utilLevel) +
             ', Object type: ' + enum2str(utilElements.recordType));
    }
}
```

Actually the AOT is cheating a little to highlight the class. The class itself is not changed, but one of its methods is.